# Java: Using created string as loop parameter?

Tags: java, loops, parameters

In short, the user will input a number (say 1 through 3).  This will decide which range of numbers the loop should search through.

```
switch(input){
case 1:
    searchTerm = "i<10 && i>5";
case 2:
    searchTerm = "i>=10 && i<19";
case 3:
    searchTerm = "i>19 && i<24";
}
while(searchTerm){
    //some function
}
```

Is this possible?  I I've not been able to find a way to use a string as search parameters.
EDIT: I don't think I did a very good job of explaining why I needed this.  What is one to do if there are different numbers of parameters?  For example:

```
case 1:
    searchTerm = "i<5"
case 2:
    searchTerm = "i>25 && i<29"
case 3:
    searchTerm = "(i<50 && i>25) && (i>55 && i<75)"
case 4:
    searchTerm = "(i<20 && i>15) && (i>300 && i<325) && (i>360 && i<380)
```

Then how does one do it?  Multiple loops that call the same function?

Comment: Why would you want to use a string for this? Use numeric variables!

Comment: No, this is not possible, not necessary and a hell to maintain and debug. You define an expression in your string, which will have to be compiled to be used.

Comment: you can use i=6;eval(searchTerm = "i<10 && i>5";) in loop

Comment: @raghavendra: Java != JavaScript

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you sorry i too missed the tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to not use a string at all:

```
int min, max;

switch(input){
case 1:      // i<10 && i>5
    min = 6;
    max = 10;
    break; // to avoid follow-through to the next case
case 2:     // i>=10 && i<19
    min = 10;
    max = 20;
    break;
case 3:     // i>19 && i<24
    min = 20;
    max = 25;
    break;
default:
    // You need something here in case the value entered wasn't 1-3
}
for (int i = min; i < max; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Re your edit:

> I don't think I did a very good job of explaining why I needed this. What is one to do if there are different numbers of parameters?

In that case, you'll have to use an expression evaluator (or write one, which is a non-trivial task). There's one in [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html), for instance (not recommending, just happened to hear about it). A search for "Java expression evaluator" should turn up some options.

Another alternative, which is somewhat amusing given that some folks mistook your question for a Java*Script* question, is to use the JavaScript evaluator built into Java (either Rhino or Nashorn). E.g.: [**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/ek2QWU)

```
import javax.script.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        String searchTerm = "i >= 19 && i <= 24";
        int i;
        try {
            i = 19;
            engine.put("i", i);
            while ((boolean)engine.eval(searchTerm)) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
                ++i;
                engine.put("i", i);
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (ScriptException scriptException) {
            System.out.println("Failed with script error");
        }
    }
}
```

...but you'll still have the problem of determining what initial value to use for `i`, which I've hardcoded above.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thanks, yes, I meant to flag that up and forgot. :-)

Comment: I didn't use correct examples, but your answer definitely answered the question that was asked.  What about the new question?

Comment: @Jimpy: I've added to the answer to address the updated question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  Your answer was extremely thorough and gives me lots of different angles to approach this problem on.  It looks like I have a whole new task to tackle.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

In *Java 8* you can select a *lambda* instead of `String`:

```
Predicate<Integer> searchTerm = (Integer v) -> false;

switch (input) {
  case 1:
    searchTerm = (Integer v) -> v < 10 && v > 5;

    break;
  case 2:
    searchTerm = (Integer v) -> v >= 10 && v < 19;

    break;
  case 3:
    searchTerm = (Integer v) -> v > 19 && v < 24;

    break;
}

while (searchTerm.test(i)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sadly thanks to the edit this no longer answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enumeration as below.

```
public enum SearchTerms {

    None(""),
    Between6And9("i<10 && i>5"),
    Between10And18("i>=10 && i<19"),
    Between20And23("i>19 && i<24");

    private final String stringValue;

    SearchTerms(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public static SearchTerms fromStringValue(String stringValue) {
        for (SearchTerms searchTerm : values()) {
            if (searchTerm.getStringValue().equalsIgnoreCase(stringValue)) {
                return searchTerm;
            }
        }
        return SearchTerms.None;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
SearchTerms searchTerm = SearchTerms.fromStringValue("i<10 && i>5");

switch(searchTerm) {
    case Between6And9:
        //dosomething
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use `.eval()` of JavaScript.

Also don't forget `break;` at the end of each `case:`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/arbzkshf/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function test(input, i) {
  switch (input) { //input=1
    case 1:
      searchTerm = "i<10 && i>5";       //this will be 'searchTerm'
      break;
    case 2:
      searchTerm = "i>=10 && i<19";
      break;
    case 3:
      searchTerm = "i>19 && i<24";
      break;
  }
  while (eval(searchTerm)) {      //'searchTerm' converted to boolean expression
    alert(i);           // alert for i=7,8,9
    i++;
  }
}

test(1, 7);           //pass input=1 and i=7
```

Comment: can be used but not a good one to use. recommend the down answer

Comment: He *could*, yes, if A) This were JavaScript instead of Java (they're completely different languages and environments), and B) He wanted to completely unnecessarily use a full JavaScript parser where simple variables were all that was needed.

Comment: meaningful to op question why down voting

Comment: @raghavendra: Read the comments. Read the question. Read the answer. Why do *you* think this is "not useful"?

Comment: @raghavendra: The **wrong language** is useful how, exactly? Shall we also post Fortran and Pascal answers? Perhaps some assembly code?

Comment: @raghavendra: Right, I give up. If you can't understand the above, I'm not going to be able to make you understand.

Comment: Sorry guys. My mistake. I didn't see the `tag`. Just saw the code. I took it to be javascript. I will delete this answer.

Comment: if the searcterm comes from textfile or some input or some ajax call what will be your response